# Xamarin.forms TimePickerDialog Android KeyBoard input

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-timepicker

i am using Xamarin.Forms TimePicker with custom renderer functionality. Everything works fine when user uses the default scroll feature of TimePickerDialog.

Issue is I want to hide the Android keyboard when user tap on the TimePickerDialog to update the time in HH:mm format.

I would be thankful for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the **InputType** of the `EditText` in Custom Renderer

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
             
               Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;
               

            }
        }
```

### Update

If you create a custom TimePicker in Android , you can also set the property `DescendantFocusability` of `TimePicker` like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using xxx.Droid;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker),typeof(MyTimePickerRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
    {
        Context Context;

        IElementController ElementController => Element as IElementController;

        public MyTimePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {

                //  Control.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.Null;

                Control.Click += Control_Click;

            }
        }

        private AlertDialog _dialog;


        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker model = Element;

            Android.Widget.TimePicker picker = new Android.Widget.TimePicker(Context);

            picker.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants;  // block keyboard here 

           var layout = new LinearLayout(Context) { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
            layout.AddView(picker);

            ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, true);

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
            builder.SetView(layout);


          
            builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel  ", (s, a) =>
            {
                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                Control?.ClearFocus();
                _dialog = null;
            });
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Ok ", (s, a) =>
            {

                ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker.TimeProperty, new TimeSpan(picker.Hour,picker.Minute,0));
                // It is possible for the Content of the Page to be changed on SelectedIndexChanged.
                // In this case, the Element & Control will no longer exist.
                if (Element != null)
                {
                    
                    ElementController.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
                    // It is also possible for the Content of the Page to be changed when Focus is changed.
                    // In this case, we'll lose our Control.
                    Control?.ClearFocus();
                }

                _dialog = null;
            });

            _dialog = builder.Create();
            _dialog.DismissEvent += (ssender, args) =>
            {
                ElementController?.SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            };
            _dialog.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for the help but somehow its not working, below is the github url,

https://github.com/ankurgupta22/TimePickerDialogSample

Please help.

Comment: I am using TimePickerDialog instead of Alert dialog with HH:mm 24 hours format.

Comment: Provide the whole project instead of tet file .

Comment: @Ankur Gupta I test your code in my project and it works fine . Only when I tap the button manually the keyboard will appear (like the above image .)

Comment: Due to security reasons i can't provide whole code. I want to disable the keyboard can you please share the code to disable the android keyboard

Comment: If you don't want to show the keyboard , I'm afraid that you could not implement it , which is up to system design . Why did you do want to disable it ?

Comment: I will pot your request to our Product Group to check if has a workaround .

Comment: I want to disable it because we already have a scroll feature to select time in HH:mm 24 hours format hence product owner wants to disable that. I believe you will also agree with the Prod Owner statement?.
Another thing in the code I provided if you select/change both HH and mm together from Android keyboard then in onTimeSet methodyou will get only one value not both. Therefore its another reason we want to remove this android keyboard feature.

If nothing works can you please provide me the sample code in 24 hours format which can read both the values together from timepickerdialog.

Comment: If you used Custom Renderer just to set 24H format , it is unnecessary . Actually , we can set it directly in xaml  `<TimePicker x:Name="timePicker" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="150" Format="HH:mm" />`

Comment: If you do want to hide the keyboard button , you can create a custom number picker (from 0-24 and 00-60).

Comment: Its not working in the code you provided Format="HH:mm", can you also please try at your end.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, can you also help me how to set width and height of alert dialog in the code which you shared above please. You code helped me a lot already.

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details so that we can help you  better .